# Why i am not receiving any data in my api route?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to do a user authentication functionality and for that i have the following route in nodejs:

```
router.post('/', [
    
    check('email', 'Plese include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Password is required').exists()
], 
async (req, res)=> {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors:errors.array()}); //400 is for bad requests
    }


    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try{
        //See if user exists

        let user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if(!user){
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg:'Invalid credentials' }] });
        }

        //Compare the input password, plane text, to the encrypted password.
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        
        if(!isMatch){
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg:'Invalid credentials' }] });
        }
    
        //Return jsonwebtoken -> this for users to be logged in right after registration

        const payload = {
            user:{
                id: user.id
            }
        }

        jwt.sign(
            payload,
            config.get('jwtSecret'),
            {expiresIn: 360000}, //change to 3600 for production
            (err, token)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json({ token });
            }
            )

    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
    

});
```

The route above works fine i can authenticate a user by trying the route in postman with no issues.

Now in reactjs i am trying to implement redux-toolkit which i am new to it.

I have the following util function to set the token:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const setAuthToken = token => {
    if(token){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
    } else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-atuh-token'];
    }
}

export default setAuthToken
```

And this is my user slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';

import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('item'),
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
    error: null
}

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/loadUser',
  async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {

    if(localStorage.token){
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth');
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
)


export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
  const body = { email, password };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth', body);

    dispatch(loadUser());

    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
  }
});

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
  },
  extraReducers: {
    
    [loadUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loadUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = false;
    },
    [loadUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.error = action.payload;

    },
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.token = localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {  } = userSlice.actions


export default userSlice.reducer
```

Above i have two functions one to load the user when the user is registered or singed in so the `token` is passed to the setAuthToken function.

So if the loadUser function is successfull i should get no errors the isAuthenticated should be true and i should get the token and the loading should be false.

Then i have my login componenent: Where i have a form and a onSubmit function where i dispatch the loginUser function from mi slice and pass the email and password being destructured from the formData. The issue is that as i submit the form i have a bad request error because it seems that i am receiving an empty object so the data is never being send or not properly received by my reducers.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../reducers/auth/authSlice';

//Material UI
import {Grid, Container, Box, Button, FormControl, InputLabel, Input, FormHelperText } from '@mui/material'

function Login({ isAuthenticated }) {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ 
    email: '',
    password: ''
    
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({
      ...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value
  });

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser(email, password))
    
  }

    return (
    <Container>
        <Box p={4}>
            <Grid container  >
                <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} >
                    <Grid item md={12}>
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id='email' 
                            type='email' 
                            name='email'
                            value={email}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your email</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id="password" 
                            type='password' 
                            name='password'
                            value={password}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your password (must have at least 6 characters)</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <Button type='submit' variant="contained" color="primary">
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: `loginUser({email, password})`

Comment: why is this? @Konrad what is the explanation?

Comment: Your function expects `{email, password}` and not `email, password`